# How to get users desktop path in python independent of language install (linux)

Tags: python, linux, path, desktop

I've found several questions and answers to "How do I find the path to the users desktop", but in my mind they are all defunct (those I found at least). The reason is that if the user has a installation of Linux that is not English, he or she may well have the desktop somewhere other than in `~/Desktop`. E.g. for Swedish, I believe it is in `~/Skrivbord`. And who knows where the user decided to place his or her desktop?

For that reason the following won't do (or any variant of it):

```
os.sep.join((os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop"))
```

So the question is:

On linux, how do I, in python, get the true path to the user's desktop without presupposing English default directory structure?

Comment: Read this page: http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs

Comment: Never seen anyone uses localized desktop directory name... But yes, it should be defined in user-dirs.dirs

Comment: @keltar I think it is default on Swedish version of Ubuntu for example (but I'm not sure)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the link, I'll check it out...

Comment: @keltar In KDE on openSUSE, dektop folder names are localized per default.

Comment: well, perhaps. russian version uses english 'Desktop', tho, don't really sure about other languages

Comment: Ok if no one wants the answer I post code based on the link above.

Comment: @keltar about half of the linux distributions localize directory names in italian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of reading directly from the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file you can call the `xdg-user-dir` utility:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['xdg-user-dir', 'DESKTOP'])
```

This will work with any linux distribution that has a DE which follow the freedesktop specification, which means: KDE, Gnome, XFCE and many more(exactly like the solution already posted by the OP).

**Edit:**

Updated the `subprocess.check_output` since arguments need to be in a list. 
Also worth pointing out that you can change DESKTOP to e.g. DOCUMENTS to get that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using @JoachimPileborg's link above: [freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs), I put together this code that should safely give the path to the user's desktop if it can be determined:

```
import os, re
def get_desktop_path():

    D_paths = list()

    try:

        fs = open(os.sep.join((os.path.expanduser("~"), ".config", "user-dirs.dirs")),'r')
        data = fs.read()
        fs.close()
    except:
        data = ""

    D_paths = re.findall(r'XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=\"([^\"]*)', data)

    if len(D_paths) == 1:
        D_path = D_paths[0]
        D_path = re.sub(r'\$HOME', os.path.expanduser("~"), D_path)

    else:
        D_path = os.sep.join((os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Desktop'))

    if os.path.isdir(D_path):
        return D_path
    else:
        return None
```

It simply tries to parse the file where the users directories should be specified and if that fails it tries to use the English default. Finally it verifies that the directory exists. I admit that the regex-expressions could probably be improved, but I think it should be OK.

Comment: Why not a simple `subprocess.check_output('xdg-user-dir')`?
This would work on english and non-english linux distributions. For windows you can fall back to join the path and `"Desktop"`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, almost right (didn't think of it) but if I understand xdg, what I'm looking for is `xdg-user-dir DESKTOP`

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't remember you had to specify `"Dekstop"` as argument.