# How to get Desktop location?

Tags: python, copy, desktop, filepath

I'm using Python on Windows and I want a part of my script to copy a file from a certain directory (I know its path) to the Desktop.

I used this:

```
shutil.copy(txtName, '%HOMEPATH%/desktop')
```

While `txtName` is the txt File's name (with full path).

I get the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%HOMEPATH%/DESKTOP'
```

Any help?

I want the script to work on any computer.

Comment: All answers (except GPCracker) are incorrect, because the desktop folder can be moved outside HOMEPATH.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `os.environ["HOMEPATH"]` to get the path.  Right now it's literally trying to find `%HOMEPATH%/Desktop` without substituting the actual path.

Maybe something like:

```
shutil.copy(txtName, os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop"))
```

Comment: `os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")` works on Linux and Windows

Comment: @dashesy: You should make that an answer - it's better than any of the others.

Answer (score 65):

On Unix or Linux:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')
```

on Windows:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
```

and to add in your command:

```
shutil.copy(txtName, desktop)
```

Comment: @BenL please vote up or accept if you found it helpful or if it solved your question.

Comment: both you and the one above you had great answers. wish I could accept to you both. voted up now. thank you!

Comment: In both Windows and Linux this seems to work: `os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")`

Comment: There is no need for the inner `os.path.join()` call. Also, the first solution works for Windows too: there is no need for the second solution.

Comment: @ChauLoi yes it is, I tested it on Mac, it gives you the parent folder of user

Comment: This is no longer reliable on Windows 10. The Desktop may be located in OneDrive, either a personal account or business.

Answer (score 37):

This works on both Windows and Linux:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

# the above is valid on Windows (after 7) but if you want it in os normalized form:
desktop = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
```

Comment: Would this work on non-English Windows machines? When I checked back around 2010 this was not the case.

Comment: @EricLebigot I do not have non-English Windows machine to test, can you let us know?

Comment: That will produce `'C:\\Users\\user/Desktop'` on Windows ... 

This will work on Win `desktop = os.path.expanduser("~\\Desktop")`

Comment: @Sabrina that is valid, in newer Widows you can use `/` and it is preferred because you won't have to escape it. You can use `os.path.normpath` if you care.

Comment: It does work on non-English (Spanish) machine, and it actually outputs what Sabrina says.

Comment: It does not work on non-English Linux machine, because my desktop folder is actually `/home/andreymal/Рабочий стол`

Answer (score 30):

For 3.5+ you can use pathlib:

```
import pathlib

desktop = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Desktop'
```

Comment: My desktop isn't located on my C:\, and all other options don't work directly. I like this solution!

Comment: This seems to be the modern way to do this.

Answer (score 14):

I can not comment yet, but solutions based on joining location to a user path with 'Desktop' have limited appliance because Desktop could and often is being remapped to a non-system drive.
To get real location a windows registry should be used... or special functions via ctypes like https://stackoverflow.com/a/626927/7273599

Answer (score 6):

All those answers are intrinsecally wrong : they only work for english sessions.

You should check the XDG directories instead of supposing it's always `'Desktop'`.

Here's the correct answer: [How to get users desktop path in python independent of language install (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741873/how-to-get-users-desktop-path-in-python-independent-of-language-install-linux)

Comment: This answer is intrinsically wrong: It only works for Linux. :)

Comment: True :) I may have been tired and forgot the bit about windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
file1 =os.environ["HOMEPATH"] + "\Desktop\myfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to @tpearse accepted answer:

In an embedded environment (c++ programm calling a python environment)

`os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")`

was the only one that worked. Seems like

`os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")`

does not return a usable path for the embedded environment (at least not in my one; But some environmental settings in visual studio could be missing in my setup)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Elegant Try this to access file in Desktop:

```
import os
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

desktop = pathlib.Path.home() / 'Desktop' / "Panda's" / 'data'
print(desktop) #check you path correct ?
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.joinn(desktop),'survey_results_public.csv')
```

Congrants!

Comment: If you clean up your answer (remove pandas / mistyped os.path.joinn that does nothing because of misplaced bracket) you end up with a duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_desktop_path():
    import platform
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        try:
            import winreg
            reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders')
            desktop = winreg.QueryValueEx(reg_key, 'Desktop')[0]
            winreg.CloseKey(reg_key)
        except:
            desktop = "None"
    else:
        from pathlib import Path
        desktop = Path.home() / 'Desktop'
        if not os.path.exists(desktop):
            desktop = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
    if not os.path.exists(desktop):
        desktop = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~"))
        print(f"архив будет сохранен сюда: {desktop}")
    else:
        print(f"архив будет сохранен на рабочий стол")
    return desktop
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).