# Write to any users desktop in Python

Tags: python

Im new to Python so apologies if this is a basic question.

I have successfully created an exe file that writes to my specific desktop directory, but I am struggling to find a way to write to any users desktop directory. 
The idea being my exe file can be copied onto any user profile and work the same. 
Here is my code:

```
 file = open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\PC info.txt','w')
```

Could somebody help me adjust my code to work on any users desktop. Thank you in advance

Comment: I searched a bit, came accross this answer here and thought it might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275782/how-to-get-desktop-location

Comment: Perhaps the OS module is what your looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the username with the os module:

```
import os

username = os.getlogin()    # Fetch username
file = open(f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\PC info.txt','w')
file.write('Hello desktop')
file.close()
```

Comment: do you know if CMD statements like `%userprofile%/desktop` will work??

Comment: Sorry. I haven't messed with windows CMD for some time. I tried a few things but could not get it to work...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `os.getlogin` with an f-string to insert the username to the file path:

```
import os

with open(fr'C:\Users\{os.getlogin()}\Desktop\PC info.txt', 'w') as f:
    # do something with f
```

But, a much better cleaner way nowadays would be to use `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib

with open(pathlib.Path.home() / "Desktop/PC info.txt", "w"):
    # do something with f
```

Also, it's always advisable to use a context manager (`with open(...) as f`) to handle files, so that the filehandler gets closed even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3.5+, you can use the following to get the path to the current user's home directory:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    home = str(Path.home())
    path = os.path.join(home, "filename.txt")
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write("HelloWorld")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
username = "MrShaun"
filename = "C:\\Users\\{0}\\Desktop\\PC info.txt".format(username)

file = open(filename, 'w')
```

In this example, filename would be: *"C:\Users\MrShaun\Desktop\PC info.txt"*

Obviously, you would probably want to build a structure around it, for example asking the user for input of a username and assigning that to the variable *username*.

Read more about formatting strings in Python [here](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: You probably want to use "username = os.getlogin()" instead, it fetches the username of the currently active user.