# Python changing directory without path

Tags: python, python-os

I would like to change the current work directory to the desktop without using os.chdir(path) since i want to use this code on different computer so the path will be different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Desktop location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275782/how-to-get-desktop-location)

Comment: Use `os.chdir` but figure out the correct desktop path using the linked question.

Comment: Sidenote though, usually you shouldn't *need* to change your working directories at all. Code that relies on current working directory can be fairly fragile. It may be a good idea to consider making your code work without affecting working directories by always using absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desktop location you can use `os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")`. This should work both in Windows and Linux, regardless of actual directories where the desktop is kept. To change directory to the current desktop you should do something like this:

```py
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multi able ways to do it :

```
import os
os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
```

Output:

> '\Users\Admin\Desktop'

```
os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")
```

Output:

> 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop'

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
```

Output:

> 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop'