# From dataframe to Excel in Desktop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, path, export-to-excel

I exported dataframe from Python to Excel. I have no problem, but I have a question if someone can help me. Can I change the path of the file without having to go through personal folders like "crisf" in my case, to save it to the desktop? I am looking for a generic route that can be applied to all computers

```
xlwriter= pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\crisf\Desktop\OHH + GIT + M3.xls')
```

Comment: seems like this is similar problem, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275921/14071081

Comment: Now I am trying with `path = os.path.relpath (r'C: \ Users \ crisf \ Desktop \ OHH + GIT + M3.xls')` . Do you know if it works for all computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that all computers will have user called "crisf". Instead use this and get universal path (path contains user’s home directory):

```
import os
***some code
xlwriter= pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop") + path of folder on desktop + file name)
```

I run `print(os.path.expanduser("~\Desktop"))`  command on my PC and got:
`C:\Users\korne\Desktop`

Comment: thanks you @kornelHub ! I am currently using this: `xlwriter= pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop\\') + r' excel_name.xls')`